# Seeding user using IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser> not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I need to insert a few seed users into the system. To do so, I have written an **ApplicationUserConfiguration** class and registered the class in the  **ApplicationDbContext** class's **OnModelCreating**. The application is working fine for the seed values but there are two issues with my implementation:

1. Every time when I generate a new migration with the **Add-Migration** command, I get the users in the Up and Down method of the migration though the users are already inserted in the database for the first time I ran the migration.
2. When I change the password, the newly changed password is working fine until I create a new migration. Every time when I create a new migration, I get the users in the Up and Down method and when running **Update-Database**, the passwords are again reset from the migration.

Could you please help me to fix the above-mentioned issues?

```
public class ApplicationUserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
        {
            PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();

            // User1
            ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = "f3a6223f-ac2d-47d9-87d7-e297ea1b78e4",
                ConcurrencyStamp = "f3a6223f-ac2d-47d9-87d7-e297ea1b78e4",
                Email = "abc@gmail.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "ABC@GMAIL.COM",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                FirstName = "User1",
                LastName = "XYZ",
                UserName = "abc@gmail.com",
                NormalizedUserName = "ABC@GMAIL.COM",
            };
            
            user.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, "Apple@123");
            builder.HasData(user);

            // User 2
            user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = "c061e936-bfc7-4b2a-95d1-644f2c19037a",
                ConcurrencyStamp = "c061e936-bfc7-4b2a-95d1-644f2c19037a",
                Email = "def@gmail.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "DEF@GMAIL.COM",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                FirstName = "User2",
                LastName = "XYZ",
                UserName = "def@gmail.com",
                NormalizedUserName = "DEF@GMAIL.COM",
            };

            user.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, "Banana@123");
            builder.HasData(user);          
        }
    }



 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ef core runs configuration and the changes add to migration when every new migration. In your case, i guess `passwordHasher` generate password by time so it will generate different hash each time.
You have to assign it statically.

```
user.PasswordHash = 'hashedPassword'
```

Comment: Actually, there needs to set two static property values i.e. PasswordHash and SecurityStamp.

Comment: SecurityStamp does not appear in question.

Comment: Yes, after fixing the PasswordHash, I saw SecurityStamp in the new migration. But anyway thanks.